# Error in User Register TypeError: res.status is not a function

Tags: node.js, express, ecmascript-6, backend

## Hi everyone I have get Error while creating backend api

```
import userModel from '../models/userModel.js';

const userRegister = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        res.status(200).jsom({
            success: true,
            message: "All work"
        })

    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error in User Register", error);

    }
};

export { userRegister };
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cq3L.png)

I just want to able fetch data  from controller  file using routes in express

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: there is typo in .json, fix it and then try.